# everytime an input field has text entered into it make progress bar width change

Tags: jquery

I have a form which has 13 fields on. I am wondering if there is any quick way to make it that every time text is entered into a field a progress bar increases by 8px for every field?

using something like `$("#progress").css("width", 8);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

concept - use a class 'track' to find all the inputs to track.  then use filter to count the number of 'track' objects which have a value.  then divide to calculate the percentage done and round down.  the percentage done can be used to move a slider or update a text label.  or as wuzz showed to use a bootstrap meter.

note: my first version tried to track the data-filled on the keyup event and populate a data-filled attribute.  but that wasn't accurate with really quick type and tab.  this solution is more robust.

HTML

```
<div>
  <span class='meter' style="display:inline-block;background:yellow;color:green;width:0;height:20px"></span>
  <span class='perc'>0</span>%
</div>
<input class="track">
<input class="track">
<input class="track">
<input class="track">
<input class="track">
<input class="track">
<input class="track">
<input class="track">
<input class="track">
<input class="track">
<input class="track">
<input class="track">
<input class="track">
<select class="track">
  <option value="">Choose One</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.track').change(function(e) {
  update_progress();
});

// supports any number of inputs and calculates done as %
function update_progress() {
  var count = $('.track').length;
  var length = $('.track').filter(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).length;
  var done = Math.floor(length * (100 / count));
  $('.perc').text(done);
  $('.meter').width(done);
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d9m7ufuv/

Comment: this works perfect too. Wondering the best way to include dropdown selects to also update this? added the class but no change. would this be right?

$('.track').change(function(e) {
  update_progress();
});

Comment: glad it helped.  updated the jsfiddle to have a select.

Comment: Jsfiddle doesnt seem to of been updated? Not sure why, could it be an issue my end?

Comment: couldn't get jsfiddle to save so made a new one and updated the answer.  can use keyup and change if desired but change works for both

Answer (score 0):

Percent is better...

```
<div id="progress" class="progress-bar progress-bar-animated progress-bar-striped bg-
success" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%" aria-valuenow="0" aria valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>


var size = 8
jQuery(function($) {
$('INPUT').on('keyup', function() {
   $('#progress').animate({width : size + '%' }, 500); 
    size = size + 8;
});
});
```

Comment: This seems to only work once, so if i type in one field it goes up by 8%. if i type in the second field it just stays at 8% doesnt add another 8% if that makes sense. any ideas?

Comment: Woops, that was my mistake.  Updated. That will work. You can see that I am telling the "size" variable to add another 8 value on each keyup.